# How can I convert encoding in a JSON result to display quotation marks correctly in HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, html-agility-pack

I need to convert either  â€œ or \u00e2\u20ac\u0153 to quotation marks when displaying.  I'm using HTML Agility Pack to fetch meta data from external web pages to display a link preview via ajax and returning a json result.  I can't work out how to convert back to quotation marks when displaying in html.

The data is coming from the external sites and isn't yet saved in my db.  HTML and ajax headers are both set to UTF-8.

I'm getting the results from HTML Agility Pack with the following code

```
var metaTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta");
    if (metaTags != null)
        {
        foreach (var tag in metaTags)
            {
            if (tag.Attributes["property"] != null && 
            tag.Attributes["content"] != null 
            && tag.Attributes["property"].Value.ToLower() == "og:description")
                {
                OgDescription = tag.Attributes["content"].Value;
                //^^returning â€œ

                //OgDescription = EncodeNonAsciiCharacters(OgDescription);
                //^^returning \u00e2\u20ac\u0153
                }
           }
       }

    var meta = new UrlPreviewDto(){
       OgDescription = OgDescription
    };

return Ok(meta);
```

I'm making the call to the web api via ajax and appending to the element in html

```
         $.post(uri,
                { '': url,
                contentType : "text/html; charset=utf-8" }
            ).done(function (data) {
                            if (data.ogDescription != "") {
                //var ogDescription = JSON.parse('"' + data.ogDescription.replace(/\"/g, '\\"') + '"');
                $('.description').append(data.ogDescription);
            }
```

The json result is returning

```
{ "url": "http://www.realbusinessrescue.co.uk/news/business-rates-are-a-ticking-timebomb-for-small-companies", "description": "Business rates are effectively a â€œticking time bombâ€ for small businesses throughout England", "title": "Business Rates Are A 'Ticking Timebomb\" For Small Companies", "ogDescription": "Business rates are effectively a â€œticking time bombâ€ for small businesses throughout England" }
```

I obviously want to display the quotation marks instead of the encoded characters.  Is there an easy way to do this in either the c# code or jquery/javascript?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: When you load the document with Agility Pack, are you checking the page's encoding and/or specifying the encoding as UTF-8? Not sure, but assuming the page is UTF-8 may also get unexpected results if the source page "isn't" UTF-8.

Comment: I'm not but looking at the page source where the response in question is coming from it is UTF-8.  I did notice that the quotation marks in the meta are curlier than normal (for want of a more technical description) <meta name="description" content="Business rates are effectively a “ticking time bomb” for small businesses throughout England" />

Answer (score 0):

If you can't manage to have the Json look nicely beforehand, you can at least correct the description afterwards using javascript.

```
$('.description').append(data.ogDescription.replace(/â€œ?/g, "\""));
```

Comment: This will work fine but I'm thinking I need to find a more robust solution which will deal with all encoded characters not just apostrophes.  Thank you for your input though.